# gdb stackoverflow

Tags: c, gdb, stack-overflow

Assume I run a program normally, it calls a certain function (say A() ) which calls itself        recursively until the stack overflows (This happened after A() got called for some 10 times) . If I run the same program under gdb, even after A() was called for more than 20 times recursively, the stack did not overflow. Is it because that I ran it under gdb that this happened, or is there any other reason?

EDIT: I'll copy paste the backtrace i obtained, Any indications to why the seg fault occured? And the bigger question is how do I locate it?

[image]

Comment: 10 seems like an awfully low number of calls for a stack overflow...

Comment: Do you have the code that behaves like this?

Comment: It's not just A(), it's like A() -> B() -> C() -> D() and D() calls A(), so the chain goes on and on till stack overflows. (10 is not the actual number, I just meant even if the same chain goes on for more number of times in gdb, it doesn't cause an overflow.

Comment: How are you tracking the number of times that A is being called?  (If it's by logging for example, you need to make sure the output is being flushed before the crash happens).

Comment: Well... as it's a recursive call and you're blowing the stack, chances are your recursion termination logic is incorrect... I assume tcmalloc.cc is your code?  what does your code look like, how are you terminating the recursion..

Comment: Of course, it's also possible that your stack has been corrupted and your backtrace doesn't mean anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because that I ran it under gdb that this happened, or is there any other reason?

Number of recursive calls allowed doesn't depend on compiler or the debugger. It is limited to the size of the stack. Assuming the program is run on same operating system, I amn't sure though about the number of recursive calls differs in your case.